# Двоеточие через каждые два символа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть форма textarea в которую ввожу мак адреса на каждой строке новый мак без двоеточий `AABBCCDDEEFF`.
По этой форме отрабатывает скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import paramiko
import datetime
import cgi
import html

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name = form.getvalue('textmac').split()
name = html.unescape(name)

print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
print("""<!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>SensorSearchFe</title>
        </head>
        <body>""")

for word in name:
    print("<br>" + word)
```

Не могу никак получить на выходе мак адрес с двоеточиями такого формата: `AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mac = 'AABBCCDDEEFF'
mac = ':'.join(mac[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(mac), 2)) 
print(mac)
# AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

Comment: всё ок, но не работает со сплитом `mac = input().split()`

Comment: @sakhalin а причем здесь `input` и `split`, если код работает над строкой?

Comment: я убрал строку, моя идея была что бы не из строки и переменной брать этот мак, а из формы на сайте, форма играет роль input. Для теста можно даже без формы `mac = input().split()` это будет похоже на работу формы, ввожу не один мак, а сразу 10 или 20 маков

Comment: @sakhalin так возьмите результат из формы и примените код

Comment: `11:22:33:44:55:66: :11:22:33:44:55:66: :11:22:33:44:55:66:`

Comment: @ Viewed всё, допилил, спасибо помогло ваше решение

Answer (score 1):

как вариант:

```
>>> line = 'AABBCCDDEEFF'
>>> print(''.join([ v+line[i+(i+1)]+':' for i, v in enumerate(line[::2]) ])[:-1])
```

Comment: @ S. Nick спасибо, тоже рабочий вариант, немного доработанный к форме